# Matlab: Peak detection for clusters of peaks

Tags: matlab, real-time, signal-processing

I am working with biological signal data, and am trying to count the number of regions with a high density of high amplitude peaks. As seen in the figure below, the regions of interest (as observed qualitatively) are contained in red boxes and 8 such regions were observed for this particular trial. The goal is to mathematically achieve this same result in near real time without the intervention or observation of the researcher.

The data seen plotted below is the result of raw data from a 24-bit ADC being processed by an FIR filter, with no other processing yet being done.

[image: Signal Data]

What I am looking for is a method, or ideally code, to help me detect such regions as identified while subsequently ignoring some of the higher amplitude peaks in between the regions of interest (i.e. between regions 3 and 4, 5 and 6, or 7 and 8 there is a narrow region of high amplitude which is not of concern). It is worth noting that the maximum is not known prior to computation.

Thanks for your help.

**Data**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oejyy6tpf5iti3j/FIRData.mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you work with thresholds?

define:
(1) "amplitude threshold": if the signal is greater than the threshold it is considered a peak

(2) "window size" : of a fixed time duration

algorithm:

if n number of peaks was detected in a duration defined in "window size" than consider the signal within "window size" as cluster of peaks.(I worked with eye blink eeg data this way before, not sure if it is suitable for your application)

P.S. if you have data that are already labelled by human, you can train a classifier to find out your thresholds and window size.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In our case since the range of values isn't known from one subject to another, how would you suggest setting the amplitude threshold when varying between subjects?

Comment: Maybe you can do a pre-screening to figure out the amplitude threshold if your experiment permits. i.e. simply observe the signal while not doing experimental manipulation and set the threshold for every subject before you start doing the real experiment. or there might be some other signal you can observe to infer the signal you are interested in... It really depends on what is your signal and the experiments you are doing...

Comment: That is what I was thinking moving forward, but how about for data which has already been collected? Can you think of a way this could be accomplished?

Comment: well you have to play with it, generally you calculate the mean and standard deviation of the signal and set the threshold at say n standard deviation (this depends on your application).

Comment: Great, thanks for your tips. I upvoted since I'm having success with peak detection thus far - will wait to accept to see if more answers incoming or will possibly post my code for others (if neither of these will accept yours :) )

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense in your problem to have some sort of "window size"?  In other words, given a region of "high" amplitude, if you shrink the duration of the region, at what point will it become meaningless to your analysis?

If you can come up with a window, just apply this window to your data as it comes in and compute the energy within the window.  Then, you can define some energy threshold and perform simple peak detection on the energy signal.

Comment: I am currently using a type of window, yes. Thanks for the idea about calculating the energy of the waveform - investigating the benefits of energy vs variance now.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection of your data, the regions with high amplitude peaks are repeated at what appears to be fairly uniform intervals.  This suggests that you might fit a sine or cosine wave (or a combination of the two) to your data.

Excuse my crude sketch but what I mean is something like this:
[image]

Once you make this identification, you can use the FFT to get the dominant spatial frequencies.  Keep in mind that the spatial frequency spectrum of your signal may be fairly complex, due to spurious data, but what you are after is one or two dominant frequencies of your data.

For example, I made up a sinusoid and you can do the calculation like this:

```
N = 255; % # of samples
x = linspace(-1/2, 1/2, N);
dx = x(2)-x(1);
nu = 8; % frequency in cycles/interval
vx = (1/(dx))*[-(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2]/N; % spatial frequency

y = sin(2*pi*nu*x); % this would be your data

F = fftshift(abs(fft(y))/N);

figure; set(gcf,'Color',[1 1 1]);
subplot(2,1,1);plot(x,y,'-b.'); grid on; xlabel('x'); grid on;
subplot(2,1,2);plot(vx,F,'-k.'); axis([-1.3*nu 1.3*nu 0 0.6]); xlabel('frequency'); grid on;
```

Which gives:

[image]

Note the peaks at ± nu, the dominant spatial frequency.  Now once you have the dominant spatial frequencies you can reconstruct the sine wave using the frequencies that you have obtained from the FFT.

Finally, once you have your sine wave you can identify the boxes with centers at the peaks of the sine waves.

This is also a nice approach because it effectively filters out the spurious or less relevant spikes, helping you to properly place the boxes at your intended locations.

Since I don't have your data, I wasn't able to complete all of the code for you, but the idea is sound and you should be able to proceed from this point.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The concern I have with this method before proceeding to implement it is that the biological phenomenon being observed does not always occur at consistent intervals. What I see when observing the data is not a sinusoid, but rather a train of exponential decay functions. Would you be able to adapt your algorithm to suit this approximation?

Comment: @iKiar, you are correct, an assumption with this approach is that your data clusters are at regular intervals.  If not at regular intervals then this might not work that well.  But if your data is consistently like the sample you show, then I think it should work ok.  If you could post examples or create a download for your raw data, I would be able to better evaluate the effectiveness of this approach to your problem.

Comment: The data has been added to the end of the question, many thanks.

Comment: @iKiar, just saw your link but I have to step out for a bit, I'll take a look at it, your data looks interesting.